# PHP Fatal error: Class Uncaught Error: Class 'Aws\Rekognition\RekognitionClient' in Sandbox

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition

I have to try AWS Rekognition API's. And am new for PHP. So, Now am using PHP code for SandBox.

Now, I got following Error,

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Aws\Rekognition\RekognitionClient' not found in [...][...]:4
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

Note: my sandbox test cases URL: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f532af13c65cff6375cdbb4058b1547f6059ec6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an online editor of PHP, it will not support to add PHP traits that can not be add in online.
So that's why it show an error that `Aws\Rekognition\RekognitionClient` is not found.
Generally we use PHP online editor to execute normal PHP code block.

Comment: thanks @Ankit Gupta. Then How can I test that one? Please Elaborate.

Comment: I think this will help you.  [https://medium.com/@iaay/laravel-aws-rekognition-sdk-integration-757518974da9].

Comment: or you can download aws-sdk-php and test Rekognition AWS API on local server. Online Editor will not help you.

Comment: [https://github.com/digitalfotografen/AWS-rekognition-demo]   I think you can use this to test  AWS credential.

Comment: @sathishanish Hope this will help you.